# Apparent velocity of winds

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, relative-motion

If I run north at 10j m/s and the wind is also blowing north at 2j m/s, then do I feel a wind of 8m/s in my face if the relative velocity of the wind to me is -8j m/s ?

Comment: Questions that have a yes/no answer are not a good fit for this site... But yes, relative to you, there is a head wind of 8 m/s . Vector addition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is in fact how vectors add.